# What exactly does Double mean in java?

Tags: java, floating-point, numbers, int, double

I'm extremely new to Java and just wanted to confirm what `Double` is? Is it similar to Float or Int? Any help would be appreciated. I also sometimes see the uppercase `Double` and other times the lower case `double`. If someone could clarify what this means that'd be great!

Comment: see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html

Comment: Even many work in Java has the same question.Cheers.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) is a wrapper class,

> The Double class wraps a value of the
>   primitive type double in an object. An
>   object of type Double contains a
>   single field whose type is double.
>
> In addition, this class provides
>   several methods for converting a
>   double to a String and a String to a
>   double, as well as other constants and
>   methods useful when dealing with a
>   double.

The [double data type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html),

> The double data type is a
>   double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754
>   floating point. Its range of values is
>    4.94065645841246544e-324d to 1.79769313486231570e+308d (positive or negative).
>   For decimal values, this data type is
>   generally the default choice. As
>   mentioned above, this data type should
>   never be used for precise values, such
>   as currency.

Check each datatype with their ranges : [Java's Primitive Data Types](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/02.html).

---

**Important Note :** If you'r thinking to use double for precise values, you need to re-think before using it. [Java Traps: double](http://firstclassthoughts.co.uk/java/traps/java_double_traps.html)

Comment: Does it represent Numbers then?

Comment: @ Yes .. It reprents a number. Look at the Number class : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html

Answer (score 29):

In a comment on @paxdiablo's answer, you asked:

> "So basically, is it better to use Double than Float?"

That is a complicated question.  I will deal with it in two parts

---

### Deciding between `double` versus `float`

On the one hand, a `double` occupies 8 bytes versus 4 bytes for a `float`.  If you have many of them, this may be significant, though it may also have no impact.  (Consider the case where the values are in fields or local variables on a 64bit machine, and the JVM aligns them on 64 bit boundaries.)  Additionally, floating point arithmetic with `double` values is typically slower than with `float` values ... though once again this is hardware dependent.

On the other hand, a `double` can represent larger (and smaller) numbers than a `float` and can represent them with more than twice the precision.  For the details, refer to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Basic_formats).

The tricky question is knowing whether you actually *need* the extra range and precision of a `double`.  In some cases it is obvious that you need it.  In others it is not so obvious.  For instance if you are doing calculations such as inverting a matrix or calculating a standard deviation, the extra precision may be critical.  On the other hand, in some cases not even `double` is going to give you enough precision.  (And beware of the trap of expecting `float` and `double` to give you an exact representation.  They won't and they can't!)

There is a branch of mathematics called Numerical Analysis that deals with the effects of rounding error, etc in practical numerical calculations.  It used to be a standard part of computer science courses ... back in the 1970's.

---

### Deciding between `Double` versus `Float`

For the `Double` versus `Float` case, the issues of precision and range are the same as for `double` versus `float`, but the relative performance measures will be slightly different.

- A `Double` (on a 32 bit machine) typically takes 16 bytes + 4 bytes for the reference, compared with 12 + 4 bytes for a `Float`.  Compare this to 8 bytes versus 4 bytes for the `double` versus `float` case.  So the *ratio* is 5 to 4 versus 2 to 1.
- Arithmetic involving `Double` and `Float` typically involves dereferencing the pointer and creating a new object to hold the result (depending on the circumstances).  These extra overheads also affect the ratios in favor of the `Double` case.

---

### Correctness

Having said all that, *the most important thing is correctness*, and this *typically* means getting the most accurate answer.  And even if accuracy is not critical, it is usually not wrong to be "too accurate".  So, the simple "rule of thumb" is to use `double` in preference to `float`, UNLESS there is an *overriding* performance requirement, AND you have solid evidence that using `float` will make a difference with respect to that requirement.

Answer (score 6):

A double is an [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) double-precision floating point number, similar to a float but with a larger range and precision.

IEEE754 single precision numbers have 32 bits (1 sign, 8 exponent and 23 mantissa bits) while double precision numbers have 64 bits (1 sign, 11 exponent and 52 mantissa bits).

A `Double` in Java is the class version of the double basic type - you can use doubles but, if you want to do something with them that requires them to be an object (such as put them in a collection), you'll need to box them up in a `Double` object.

Comment: So basically, is it better to use `Double` than `Float`?

Comment: @maclunian : Float is wrapper class, float is the primitive data type. Please visit above mentioned oracle link. You will get all the difference.

Comment: @maclunian, it's a trade-off. Obviously doubles take up twice as much space and _may_ be slower for computations, but thet do provide the greater range and precision. You should use doubles where they're necessary (same as for _any_ data type).