# Mathematical representation of double in java

Tags: java, math, floating-point

I would like to specify a set that exactly covers the number range for double / float.

For `Integer` it's quite easy because they are all natural numbers from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so

> INTEGER = { x e ℕ | x ≤ 2147483647<sup>x</sup> ≥ -2147483648 }

For `double` and `float` it's harder because of the precision of that data types

### EDIT:

To ask for "a mathematical representation" may be a bit imprecise. So what do I need:

I'm looking for a definition that fits this pattern:

> Double = { x e ℝ | x ≤ 2<sup>-1022<sup>x</sup></sup> ≥ -2<sup>-1074<sup>{insert further conditions here}</sup></sup> }

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319727/what-exactly-does-double-mean-in-java

Comment: What do you accept as specification? For example would "the set of all numbers representable by IEEE 754-2008 floating point format" be a specification?

Comment: There is the classic: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 3):

Well, the extreme values are [`Double.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) and [`Double.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE). As computers are discreet entities and real number are continuous there are "holes" in this range.

The gory details are in [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Answer (score 2):

Without infinity and special values like *NaN*, the real values are actually rational numbers

- *Double_normal* = { x ∈ ℚ | **x = (-1)<sup>sign</sup> × 1.mantissa × 2<sup>exp - bias</sup>**, 1 ≤ exp ≤ 2046 }
- *Double_subnormal* = { x ∈ ℚ | **x = (-1)<sup>sign</sup> × 0.mantissa × 2<sup>-1022</sup>** }
- *Double* = *Double_normal* ⋃ *Double_subnormal* ⋃ { 0 }

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea and ignoring constants and some special cases (normalization, hidden one, gradual underflow, ... - you can work out the details), the representable numbers are basically

```
M * 2^E where MMIN <= M <= MMAX and EMIN <= E <= EMAX
```

This is by the way even a subset of the rational numbers. It is not possible to represent irrational numbers in this format.

On the other hand, there are also several values, that are not numbers at all.